# UV mapping or texture not conforming to topology

Tags: texturing, uv, topology

I made a well done model and applied some mean creases to have corners on specific edges of my model. All good, but I noticed that, behind my model, the texture is not applied correctly, even if the UV mapping was pinned before texturing and the mean creases on that two edges is 1 (in green). I noticed that I have the same problem on another part (in yellow).

[image]

I cannot explain it. I tried to:
- Apply the scale
- Remove doubles both on both my UV map and my topology.

What can cause this issue?

I 'll attach my texture as well. I enabled the UV map level, so you have a better feel.

[image: Texture]

Comment: Looks like some UV mapping problem but it could be result of a topo problem. Share the file using this please: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ **Also use the Smooth shading instead of that much SubDiv levels.**

Comment: You can find it here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AkFTgZyIwsOp3xaIjqjzzHtgEyB5